# Como juntar 2 listas em um dicionário?

Tags: python

Quero pegar 2 listas e transformá-las num dicionário, em que cada item tenha como chave o i-ésimo item da primeira lista e como valor o i-ésimo item da segunda lista.

Fiz esse código até agora:

```
lista_de_compras = ['arroz', 'feijao', 'macarrao']
preco_dos_itens = ['2.00', '3.80', '4.90']

lista_nova = {}

for item in lista_de_compras:
    for preco in preco_dos_itens:
        lista_nova[item] = preco

print(lista_nova)
```

Porém, quando eu *printo* essa lista_nova (que no caso é o dicionário), ele aplica os itens corretamente nas chaves, porém não entendi o pq ele repetir em todos só o último preço do item pra todos os itens, e como resolver esse problema:

output:

> {'arroz': '4.90', 'feijao': '4.90', 'macarrao': '4.90'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você aninhou os `for`.

Tome como exemplo este trecho:

```py
for preco in preco_dos_itens:
    print(preco)
```

Ele irá iterar sobre todos os preços, printando um de cada vez. Analogamente...

```py
for item in lista_de_compras:
    print(item)
```

Printa todos os itens. Tá, e quando eu faço isso?

```
for item in lista_de_compras:
    for preco in preco_dos_items:
        print(f'{item} {preco}')
```

Estarei combinando todos os itens com todos os preços. Ou seja, a saída será

```
arroz 2.0
arroz 3.8
arroz 4.9
feijao 2.0
feijao 3.8
feijao 4.9
macarrao 2.0
macarrao 3.8
macarrao 4.9
```

Pra ter o comportamento correto, você precisa iterar pelos *índices*.

```
numero_de_itens = len(lista_de_compras)
for i in range(numero_de_itens):
  print(f'{lista_de_compras[i]} {preco_dos_itens[i]})'
```

Comment: A solução do Naslauky é mais idiomática (ou pythônica), mas é bom você saber como isso se passa em um nível mais baixo de abstração.

Comment: Perfeito amigo, me ajudou de mais, era exatamente isso que minha linha de raciocino queria chegar hahaha

Conhecendo mais do for, a compreensão de muita coisa veio junto.

Answer (score 7):

O que você deseja é a função interna `zip()` ([documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)).

Essa função recebe uma lista de iteradores, e retorna um novo iterador, em que cada elemento é uma tupla contida por um elemento correspondente de cada iterador original.

Exemplo: Se a lista `A = [1,2,3]` e a lista `B=[4,5,6]`, então `zip(A,B)` irá retornar `(1,4), (2,5), (3,6)`.

Aplicando em seu caso, temos:

```
lista_de_compras = ['arroz', 'feijao', 'macarrao']
preco_dos_itens = ['2.00', '3.80', '4.90']
dict = {}
for i,j in zip(lista_de_compras, preco_dos_itens):
    dict[i] = j
print(dict) // {'arroz': '2.00', 'feijao': '3.80', 'macarrao': '4.90'}
```

O que você estava fazendo anteriormente, (isto é, vários `for` aninhados) não funcionava pois para cada caso único, você percorria a segunda lista inteira, o que não era o desejado.

Comment: Um modulo muito bom e que facilita bastante, eu pelo menos, não conhecia essa função. Muito obrigado por compartilhar.

Answer (score 6):

É desnecessário em python montar laços de iteração para criar dicionários a partir de duas listas de mesmo comprimento. Apenas agregue as listas com a função embutida [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#zip) e passe o resultado obtido como argumento para o [constructor do dicionário](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict):

```
lista_de_compras = ['arroz', 'feijao', 'macarrao']
preco_dos_itens = ['2.00', '3.80', '4.90']

d = dict(zip(lista_de_compras, preco_dos_itens))

print(d)     #{'arroz': '2.00', 'feijao': '3.80', 'macarrao': '4.90'}
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/GJNrC0) e teste no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/juntarlistas#main.py)</sup>

Comment: Aqui a caso para dizer que primeiro valeu mais que o melhor d:. Esta foi a melhor

Answer (score -4):

```
keys = ['Dez', 'Vinte', 'Trinta']
values = [10, 20, 30]
dicionario = {}
for i in range(len(keys)):    
    dicionario.update({keys[i]: values[i]})
print(dicionario)
```